# Finding and returning a loopy path in a directed graph

Tags: algorithm, scala, graph

I wrote a function in Scala to find out and return a loopy path in a directed graph.

One of the arguments is a graph presented in an adjacent list, and the other is a start node. It returns a pair including a loopy path by a list of nodes.

I wonder if there are more elegant ways of doing this.

```
  def GetACycle(start: String, maps: Map[String, List[String]]): (Boolean, List[String]) = {
    def explore(node: String, visits: List[String]): (Boolean, List[String]) = {
      if (visits.contains(node)) (true, (visits.+:(node)).reverse)
      else {
        if (maps(node).isEmpty) (false, List())
        else {
          val id = maps(node).indexWhere(x => explore(x, visits.+:(node))._1)
          if (id.!=(-1))
            explore(maps(node)(id), visits.+:(node))
          else
            (false, List())
        }
      }
    }
    explore(start, List())
  }
```

I felt I had to use the `indexWhere` in this situation, but I suppose it would have other ways to do that.

Comment: I am not familiar with scala. If the question is about the algorithm, yes there are some interesting ones. Start here: http://ostermiller.org/find_loop_singly_linked_list.html go there http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_detection or there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/546655/finding-all-cycles-in-graph and continue with any scientific research for `cycle detection` (+ graphs). The Tortoise and Hare algorithm could be called short and easy while still valid. If this counts for elegant, you may give it a try.

Comment: @tb, I will look into these. Thanks for your suggestions! Fantastic!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use an array to check if you have already visited a node and not `visits.contains(node)`, it would give you the answer in constant time instead of linear time.

The overall complexity of your algorithm is exponential. For instance, if you run your algorithm on this graph:

```
0 -> 1, 2, ..., n
1 -> 2, ..., n
...
```

where there are `n` nodes and there are edges from `i` to `j` iff `i<j` then the node `i` will be explored `2^i` times.

Again you can solve this problem using an array (one array for all nodes) to ensure that each node is explored at most one time.